# Nginx rewrite problem - displaying same page with or without .php extension after rewrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx, ubuntu, clean-urls

I have implemented the following Nginx code:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

It's successful in removing the `.php` extension, but the page also loads with the `.php` extension. For example, both `http://example.com/pages/page.php` and `http://example.com/pages/page` work.

Kindly help me so that the page only loads without the `.php` extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

This config matches `/pages/page.php`.
In this case `$uri` (the first argument of `try_files`) is `/pages/page.php`.
Thefore, if this file exists, nginx return contents of the file.

If you want to return 404 for any requests with `.php` extension, following setting is correct.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```